# Unable to navigate to radio option in group from a previous input on hitting tab key

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

Select Yes and hit the tab key - you go to the input text box - hit tab again and you can't select No - it directly jumps to the Go Back link. Why am I not able to select **No** on tab from the input text ?

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="code" id="code-yes" />
        <span>Yes</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Enter your code (optional)</legend>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0000-0000-0000 " />
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <br/>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="code" id="code-no" />
        <span>No, I don't have a code</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#">Go Back</a>
  </div>
</div>
```